Time limit for reunion of lovers after death
I am trying to remember the name of a movie.  The plot goes something like this:
Two lovers die, and they beg God for some more time on Earth together.  God agrees to re-incarnate them as different people, but they have a time limit on getting together.  If they do not get together within a certain age, they will both die and come back to Heaven.  It has similar plot elements as Heaven Can Wait, but it is a different movie.

Possibly Made in Heaven from 1987. From TVTropes:

After the male lead Mike (Timothy Hutton) dies in a Heroic Sacrifice, he goes to Heaven and meets his One True Love: Annie (Kelly McGillis), a newborn female soul yet to be conceived on Earth. They fall in love and get married, but Annie is sent to incarnate for her first time on Earth; Mike chooses to reincarnate to find her, and is given 30 years to do so.

Here's the trailer:



